# What is the grammatical difference between: “is borrowed” and " has been borrowed"?

Tags: grammar

These are the sentences:

> My umbrella **is borrowed** by Tom. May I use yours？
>   My umbrella **has been borrowed** by Tom. May I use yours?

I wrote the first sentence as my answer in my grammar quiz, but my teacher said that I'm wrong. And the answer should be the second one.

What is the difference in these two sentence and is my sentence correct?
Thank you very much.

ps. I am the one who post the last post, but I lost my account, so I post it again.

Answer (score 3):

> My umbrella is borrowed by Tom.

Isn't exactly wrong, but it doesn't sound natural.  The umbrella is in a state of having been borrowed.

> My umbrella has been borrowed by Tom.

Sounds better but still kind of stiff.  This is talking about the act of borrowing, being in the past, with emphasis on the umbrella as the thing being borrowed rather than on Tom doing the borrowing.

> My umbrella was borrowed by Tom.

This is how I would phrase it if I wanted to use the passive voice.  I might use this if I want to emphasize the umbrella over Tom.  The meaning in this situation is the effectively same as "has borrowed" but it sounds better.  In other situations though "was" and "has been" have different meanings.

> Tom borrowed my umbrella.

Using the active voice, this is what I would normally say as a native speaker.  Emphasis here is on Tom doing the borrowing, but the reason I'd say it this way is just that the active voice "sounds better" than the passive voice.

Answer (score -1):

These two sentences were written in Passive Voice.

> `My umbrella is borrowed by Tom. May I use yours？`

the first sentence is in the Simple Present tense According to Passive Voice.

**Active Voice:** `Tom borrows my umbrella.` **`(Simple Present)`**

this tense refers the General activities and also refers indefinite aspects.

Here we are not concluded that whether tom has already borrowed or not.

> `My umbrella has been borrowed by Tom. May I use yours?`

The second statement is also written in Present perfect tense according to Passive Voice.

**Active Voice:** `Tom has borrowed my umbrella.` **`Present Perfect`**

this tense refers just completed actions means all definite aspects.

Here we are concluded that action already completed.